# Scroll snapping in Vue.js/Nuxt.js with Tailwind CSS creates an additional scrollbar

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Vue.js project and trying to implement scroll snapping for my hero sections using Tailwind CSS. However, while I can get the scroll snapping to work, it introduces an additional scrollbar for the `main` element. I want a single scrollbar for the entire page that controls the snapping behavior.

Here's the relevant CSS from my `tailwind.css`:

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";

body {
  @apply overflow-x-hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hero-snap-section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And the relevant Vue template from `index.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    <!-- First Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section">
      <!-- ... other content ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... other sections ... -->
  </main>
</template>
```

I also have a `default.vue` layout:

```js
<template>
  <div class="min-h-screen bg-background">
    <!-- Header -->
    <Navbar />
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <Nuxt />
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="bg-background">
      <!-- ... footer content ... -->
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've ensured that the `hero-snap-section` class is applied to the sections I want to snap to. However, when I scroll, the sections don't snap as expected.

To introduce snap scrolling, I tried:

```css
main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hero-snap-section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This works, but it creates a second scrollbar for my `main`, which is not what I want.

I've tested this on both Chrome and Edge. Here's a fuller code snippet for visualization:

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hero-snap-section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid red; /* For visualization */
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Content -->
<main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    <!-- First Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwgnjyezw/image/upload/e_improve,w_500,h_500,c_thumb,g_auto/v1693301320/samples/animals/three-dogs.jpg" alt="Banner Image">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia odio vitae vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwgnjyezw/image/upload/e_improve,w_500,h_500,c_thumb,g_auto/v1693301320/samples/animals/three-dogs.jpg" alt="Banner Image">
        <p>Donec sit amet nisl. Aliquam semper ipsum sit amet velit. Suspendisse id sem consectetuer libero luctus adipiscing.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- ... Repeat for other sections ... -->
</main>
```

**Desired Scroll Hierarchy**:

1. **Header** (`Navbar` component from `default.vue`)
2. **Main Content** (`<main>` from `index.vue`)

   - Content Section 1 (`hero-snap-section`)
   - Content Section 2 (`hero-snap-section`)
   - Content Section 3 (`hero-snap-section`)
   - ...
3. **Footer** (`footer` from `default.vue`)

   - Newsletter Signup
   - Contact Information
   - ...

I want the entire page to have a single scrollbar. When scrolling, the page should snap to each of the main content sections (`hero-snap-section`). The header and footer should not have any snapping behavior but should be part of the overall scrollable content.

Any ideas on how to have scroll snapping on the `main` sections while maintaining a single scrollbar for the entire page, or is this not possible?

---

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having the `html` element be the scroll container that has the scroll snapping. This would mean that any children could snap:

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hero-snap-section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="min-h-screen bg-background">
  <!-- Header -->
  <Navbar>Navbar</Navbar>
  <!-- Page Content -->

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <main class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    <!-- First Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero-snap-section bg-red-200">
      <!-- ... other content ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="hero-snap-section bg-yellow-200">
      <!-- ... other content ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="hero-snap-section bg-green-200">
      <!-- ... other content ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... other sections ... -->
  </main>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-background">
    <!-- ... footer content ... -->
  </footer>
</div>
```